# How to override template_name in SelectDateWidget (Django 1.11)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-widget

I need to wrap the fields in div. 
In Django 1.10:

```
class CustomSelectDateWidget (SelectDateWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
       ...
       output = []
       for field in self._parse_date_fmt():
            if field == 'year':
                output.append('<div class="input-field col s4">' + html['year'] + '</div>')
            elif field == 'month':
                output.append('<div class="input-field col s5">' + html['month'] + '</div>')
            elif field == 'day':
                output.append('<div class="input-field col s3">' + html['day'] + '</div>')
        return mark_safe('\n'.join(output))
```

It dosn`t work in Django 1.11.
I tried to override 'django/forms/widgets/select_date.html':

```
class CustomDateWidget(SelectDateWidget):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return ['accounts/custom_select_date.html']
```

But Django include 'django/forms/widgets/select_date.html' instead of my template 'accounts/templates/accounts/custom_select_date.html'. No error messages are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a simple way to do it. In my case I wanted to show the image in an ImageField. Here's teh codez:

Copy django's `clearable_file_input.html` template, customise it and save it to, e.g. `django_overrides/forms/widgets/clearable_file_input.html`, e.g.:

```
{% if is_initial %}{{ initial_text }}: <img src="{{ widget.value.url }}" />{% if not widget.required %}
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ checkbox_name }}" id="{{ checkbox_id }}" />
<label for="{{ checkbox_id }}">{{ clear_checkbox_label }}</label>{% endif %}<br />
{{ input_text }}:{% endif %}
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %} />
```

Subclass the original widget, setting the `template_name` to your new template:

```
from django.forms import ClearableFileInput

class CustomClearableFileInputWidget(ClearableFileInput):
    template_name = 'django_overrides/forms/widgets/clearable_file_input.html'
```

Update your forms to use this widget:

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['id', 'user']
        widgets = {
            'photo': CustomClearableFileInputWidget,
        }
```

Comment: You can also in the UserProfileForm: `ClearableFileInput.template_name = 'django_overrides/forms/widgets/clearable_file_input.html'` without creating the CustomClearableFileInputWidget, but this override all ClearableFileInput int the current form.

Answer (score 1):

use super to override it as you are using an class parent to create child class

```
form = super(CustomSelectDateWidget , self).get_form(form_class)
```

Comment: Thank you. I found another way to solve this SelectDateWidget.template_name = 'accounts/custom_select_date.html'

Comment: @ctac Please can you create an answer with your other way? Did you still have to subclass the widget?